# Why is webpack dev server not starting up my express server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a simple web app I'm building using express and react. I am serving the entire front-end React bundle via my express server.

Currently my start script is working just fine, it builds the front-end code and starts up my express server. When I navigate to the app in my browser everything works find, front and back ends. However when I run my dev script my backend endpoints do not work so I am getting errors and the frontend never renders.

The whole source can be found [here](https://github.com/int-a/contacts) but I'll put the relevant files below:

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './client/index.js',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: { 
              presets: ['@babel/preset-react']
            }
        }
      }, {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader'
        }, {
        test: /\.css$/,
  loader: 'css-loader',
  query: {
    modules: true,
    localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
  }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  },
  devtool:"#eval-source-map"
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "contacts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple contacts app written using React, Node, and Mongo",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npx webpack --mode=development && node server/server.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode=development",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development"
  },
...
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It's running on `http://localhost:8080` however, you have an odd implementation of wrapping your entire `ReactDOM.render` function within a promise. In addition, if data is missing, it results in a `TypeError: this.props.contacts.map is not a function` and nothing is displayed.

API fetch calls should be placed inside a component's `componentDidMount` lifecycle. Then that `class component` should return some [conditionally rendered](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) component based upon the response. You'll need to handle all scenarios where data is present, data is missing, and/or there was an API error (otherwise, it'll crash your application).

**Working API example** (specifically look at `containers/Users/index.js` or the example code written below):

[image: Edit API Example w/ Axios Mock Testing]

---

**containers/Users/index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import app from "../../utils/axiosConfig";
import ShowData from "../../components/ShowData";
import ShowError from "../../components/ShowError";
import ShowLoading from "../../components/ShowLoading";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
    hasError: "",
    isLoading: true
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      this.fetchData("users"); // calling "fetchData" after 1.5seconds (not necessary, but this way, you'll see a "Loading" component when data isn't present yet)
    }, 1500);
  };

  fetchData = url =>
    app
      .get(`${url}`) // makes a request to the API
      .then(res => { // handles a successful API response
        if (!res.data) throw new Error("No data was found!");
        this.setState({ isLoading: false, data: res.data });
      })
      .catch(err => // handles an API error or no data response
        this.setState({ isLoading: false, hasError: err.toString() })
      );

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true, data: [] }, () => {
      this.fetchData("todos");
    });
  };

  // the code below utilizes a ternary operator: if cond ? then : else 
  // (shorthand for if/else or if/elseif/else ...etc)
  // the code below can be read as: if isLoading is true, then return
  // "<ShowLoading/>"; if it's false, but there was an error, then
  // return "<ShowError ... />", else if isLoading is false and 
  // hasError is false, then return "<ShowData ... />"
  render = () => (
    <div className="app-container">
      {this.state.isLoading ? (
        <ShowLoading />
      ) : this.state.hasError ? (
        <ShowError error={this.state.hasError} />
      ) : (
        <ShowData data={this.state.data} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean about wrapping the DOM render function in a promise. I was trying to feed my initial state for redux this way, it felt wrong at the time and I never went back to re-do it. This won't really fix my problem though, will it? My express server is still not serving anything on those endpoints

Comment: I'd separate the front-end from the back-end. Right now, you're trying to host both on the same port. Instead, webpack-dev-server should serve on port `3000` and your API on port `5000`. When compiled, everything will be served on port `8080`. Use `concurrently` to run two processes with one command, for example: `"concurrently \"npm run server\" \npm run dev --prefix client\"`